# Pandas DataFrame Not Dropping Rows based on String Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having some trouble with filtering a dataset based on string values. I have tried multiple methods and none of them seem to work. I have data which looks like the following:

[image]

Some of the "CountryNames" in this dataset are "Unknown", like the following:

[image]

I would like to filter out the rows with the "Unknown" value in CountryNames. I have tried mulitple methods and none of them seem to work for some odd reason. They just produce the exact same dataset as before.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\DylanNdengu\Downloads\combined_table.xlsx", index_col=False)

located_data = data[~data["CountryNames"].isin(["Unknown"])]
```

data and located data have the exact same shape, and the rows with Unknown are still there. Please also note I have also tried the following commands:

```
located_data = data[~data["CountryNames"].isin(["Unknown"])==True]
located_data = data[data["CountryNames"].isin(["Unknown"])==False]
located_data = data[data["CountryNames"]!="Unknown"]
```

All of these are not working either. Please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix this. The dtype for the CountryNames column is "object" if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your image examples it looks like the values in your data are actually misspelled as `Uknown` rather than the correct `Unknown`. Otherwise your code seems correct.

Try this:

```
located_data = data[~data["CountryNames"].isin(["Uknown"])]
```

Alternatively you should fix your data by renaming the mispelled names with the correct ones, for example by using:

```
data[data["CountryNames"]=="Uknown"] = "Unknown"
```

Comment: No it is spelt right

Comment: You're quite right. I had not seen it was spelt this way in the dataset. Thank you so much, I really appreciate it. I have clearly been looking at this thing too long.